# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

`Webform1.aspx` has grid.Grid contain edit button. On click of edit button, user is redirected to `webform2.aspx` page. A Querystring id is passed to `Webform2.aspx`. `Webform2.aspx` shows all  data of that id. Webform contain dropdownlist, textboxes and button etc.

I am fetching record from database and assigning to control like dropdownlist, textbox and button. When assigning value to textbox that contain `<` or `>` and trying to update the record. It throws an exception. Exception is `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`. So I tried to use htmlencode method.

Below is my code
In cs file

```
 public partial class Webform1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
     string strUrl="";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // Fetching value from database and assigning to string   
    Textbox1.Text= dr["URL"].ToString();
    // directly use string 
   //strUrl= dr["URL"].ToString();
    }

    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
    string s2 ="";  
    string s3 = "";             
    strUrl= Textbox1.Text;                   
         if ((strUrl.Contains("<")) || (strUrl.Contains(">")))
         {
           s2 = Server.HtmlEncode("<");
           s3 = Server.HtmlEncode(">");
           strUrl= strPingUrl.Replace("<", s2);
           strUrl= strPingUrl.Replace(">", s3);                                    
       }
     Textbox1.Text =strUrl; 
    // updation code
```

When I will try to insert it throws exception.Instead of assigning value to textbox if i use string.It is working. I am able to update the record. But I don't want like this. User can change the value in textbox. So I want to take value from textbox.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client?rq=1

Comment: Yes I visited that page.I don't want use this code. <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Try http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423413/Submit-HTML-Text-with-Page-Validation-Turned-On

Comment: I have one suggestion. Use Webmethod/webservice and jquery ajax to submit the data with plain html form elements. However, I'm still unsure whether this will also encounter similar issue or not. I have not tried.

Answer (score -1):

To disable request validation on a page you must set the validateRequest attribute of the Page directive to false:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

To disable request validation for your application, you must modify or create a Web.config file for your application and set the validateRequest attribute of the  section to false:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you wish to disable request validation for all applications on your server, you can make this modification to your Machine.config file.

In .NET 4 you may need to add to web.config:

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Details:

1. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation
2. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc245724857

Comment: Yes I know that.But I don't want to make validaterequest false.

Comment: This is not a recommended approach unless you really know what you are doing.